# Unknown reason for hidden fields nested forms ruby on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, haml

I am developing a simple rails app which is supposed to a concert registration app. What is basically supposed to do is get infos from a person and then save them in the `DB` also generate an a ticket with a unique id. The issue is that the form is no showing the fields for the tickets. The only time when those fields show is when there is an error somewhere.
[image]

```
participants_controller
    def new
        @participant = Participant.new
        @ticket = @participant.tickets.build
      end

      def create
        @participant = Participant.new(participant_params)
        @ticket = @participant.tickets.build
        1.times{@ticket}
        if @participant.save
          flash[:success] = "An Email as been sent to #{@participant.email}"
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render :new
        end
      end

      private
      def participant_params
        params
            .require(:participant)
            .permit(:first_name,:last_name,:phone,:email,:gender,:email_confirmation,:participant_id,
                    :tickets_attributes => [:id,:vip,:quantity])
      end
```

then here is the form

```
= simple_form_for @participant do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :first_name
  = f.input :last_name
  = f.input :phone
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :email_confirmation
  = f.input :gender, collection: ['M','F'], as: :radio_buttons
  = f.simple_fields_for :tickets do |ticket|
    = ticket.input :vip , label: 'Want a vip ticket? ',collection: ['No','Yes'] , include_blank: false
    = ticket.input :quantity , label: 'How many tickets?' , include_blank: false, collection: 1..100
  = f.button :submit , 'Get Tickets'
```

then the models

```
ticket model
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :participant
  # validates :quantity, presence: true
  validates :participant , presence: true
end




participant model
class Participant < ApplicationRecord

  validates :first_name,:last_name, presence: true
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
            confirmation: true
  validates :email_confirmation, presence: true
  VALID_PHONE_NUMBER = /\d/
  validates :phone, presence: { message: "Won't give it to NSA promise" }, format:{with: VALID_PHONE_NUMBER},
            length: {is: 11}
  has_many :tickets , inverse_of: :participant
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tickets,
                                reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['kind'].blank?}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in your create action:

```
@ticket = @participant.tickets.build
```

Is what adds the tickets. So with rails nested forms, or when even using simple_form, you need to instantiate the child relationship with the number of records you want. So it will loop through them and display them as such. So if you want one ticket when the `new` action renders, simply call:

```
@participant.tickets.build
```

In the new action.

Comment: Thanks that solved an issue.
Now I am realizing that nothing concerning the `Ticket` is being saved in the `db`. I get all `nil` apart from the id. any clue?

Comment: The participant is saving, but the ticket is not? I see you put a reject_if block containing: `attributes['kind'].blank?`, but i don't see a reference to a kind attribute anywhere. Is that something you're using?

Comment: I think that was a bad copy paste from the internet. participant is saving and ticket is saving as well but it only saves the times of creation and update but other attributes aren't being saved.

Comment: Check the rails server logs to see if strong_parameters is blocking anything on getting through. Might need to adjust your permit() call

Comment: I don't know what happened but after restarting the server it worked thanks a lot for the help mate.